# Live Stream from AWS MediaLive service not viewable from VLC

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, live-streaming, aws-media-live, aws-mediastore

I am trying to build a custom live streaming service as documented here:

https://aws.amazon.com/solutions/implementations/live-streaming-on-aws/

I used the pre-provided cloudformation template for "Live Streaming on AWS with MediaStore" which provisioned all the relevant resources for me. Next, I wanted to test my custom streamer.

I used OBS Studio to stream my webcam output to MediaLivePushEndpoint that was created during AWS cloudformation provisioning. OBS Suggests that it is already streaming the webcam stream to the rtmp endpoint to AWS MediaLive RTMP endpoint.

Now, to confirm if I can watch the stream, when I try to set the Input Nerwork Stream in VLC player to the cloudfront endpoint that was created for me (which looks like this: https://aksj2arbacadabra.cloudfront.net/stream/index.m3u8), VLC is unable to fetch the stream and fails with the following error message in the logs. What am I missing? Thanks!

```
...
...
...
http debug: outgoing request: GET /stream/index.m3u8 HTTP/1.1 Host: d2lasasasauyhk.cloudfront.net Accept: */* Accept-Language: en_US User-Agent: VLC/3.0.11 LibVLC/3.0.11 Range: bytes=0- 
http debug: incoming response: HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found Content-Type: application/x-amz-json-1.1 Content-Length: 31 Connection: keep-alive x-amzn-RequestId: HRNVKYNLTdsadasdasasasasaPXAKWD7AQ55HLYBBXHPH6GIBH5WWY x-amzn-ErrorType: ObjectNotFoundException Date: Wed, 18 Nov 2020 04:08:53 GMT X-Cache: Error from cloudfront Via: 1.1 5085d90866d21sadasdasdad53213.cloudfront.net (CloudFront) X-Amz-Cf-Pop: EWR52-C4 X-Amz-Cf-Id: btASELasdasdtzaLkdbIu0hJ_asdasdasdbgiZ5hNn1-utWQ== 
access error: HTTP 404 error
main debug: no access modules matched
main debug: dead input
qt debug: IM: Deleting the input
main debug: changing item without a request (current 2/3)
main debug: nothing to play
```

---

- Updates based on Zach's response:

Here are the parameters I used while deploying the cloudformation template for live streaming using MediaLive (notice that I am using RTMP_PUSH):

[image]

I am using `MediaLive` and not `MediaPackage` so when I go to `MediaLive` to my channel, I see this:

[image]

Notice that it says that it cannot find the "stream [stream]" but I confirmed that the rtmp endpoint I add to my OBS is exactly the one which was created as an output for me from my cloudformation stack:

[image]

Finally, when I try to go to media store to see if there are any objects, it is completely empty:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Vader,

Thank you for the clarification here, I can see the issue is with your settings in OBS.  When you setup your input for MediaLive you created a unique Application Name and Instance.  Which is part of the URI, the Application Name is LiveStreamingwithMediaStore and the Instance is stream, in OBS you are going to want remove stream from the end of the Server URI and place it in the Stream Key portion, where you currently have a 1.

OBS Settings:

Server: rtmp://server_ip:1935/Application_Name/

Stream Key: Instance_Name

Since you posted the screenshot here on an open forum, which really helped determine the issue, but does expose settings that would allow someone to send to the RTMP input I would suggest that you change the Application Name and Instance.

Zach

Comment: I just updated this thread with as much info as I could provide from the questions you asked me.